# How to move object in the direction of rotation in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a "car" which has to be moved in the direction which it is rotated.
Now it just rotates in a direction and keeps on going up and down.Please help me.
I am using adobe flash pro cs6 and actionscript3.
My code is :

```
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

car.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        car.y += 5;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        car.y -= 5;
    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        car.rotation += 5;
    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        car.rotation -= 5;
    }
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your function **fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey** moves your car in absolute values of x and y. There is no room for any rotation or relative movement. You should add to your car a vector variable for it's position and a vector variable for it's direction. Then you should start reading into vector math and how to rotate and translate vectors. Finally you apply rotation first (which then means ot rotates locally, around it's own axis) and then translation (which means you place it on the screen where It's x and y are intended to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [vector math](http://www.helixsoft.nl/articles/circle/sincos.htm) to move the car's `x,y` based on an angle and a distance.

For example, you could move your car based on an angle and speed like this:

```
function move(degrees:Number, speed:Number):void {
    var radians:Number = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    car.x += Math.cos(radians) * speed;
    car.y += Math.sin(radians) * speed;
}
```

Then you can use the car's `rotation` as the angle and `5` or `-5` as the speed:

```
if (upPressed) {
    move(car.rotation, 5);
}
if (downPressed) {
    move(car.rotation, -5);
}
```

Note that this assumes `rotation=0` means your car is facing right-ward. If you've draw your car facing a different direction you'll need to compensate for the angle you've drawn the car, for example if the car is facing upward you need to use `move(car.rotation - 90, 5)`.